# Android native process pauses after 10 to 15 seconds

Tags: android, process, android-ndk, native

I have an Android Java app, and also a native app.
The native app is launched from the Java app, like this:

mProcess = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmdLaunch, null, new File(files_dir));

The native process actually runs in a loop, and sleeps once in a while to yield.

Here's what is happening. After the native process is launched, it runs for about 10 to 15 seconds. After that it just pauses.
The Java app is still in the foreground.
I know this from the logcat logs. There is nothing that'll make it resume.

Because I'm developing it, I start a new debugging session.
This kills the previous Java app, and starts a new one.

Now the native process, which was paused, resumes and continues running as expected.
Now this runs indefinitely without pausing.

What is happening here?

When the parent process (Java app) was killed, should the child process (native app) also have been killed?
And how come as soon as the parent process was killed, the native process started to run without any issues.

Comment: Use the ndk gdb (manually) or strace to attach to the native process and figure out what it is up to.  Also try modifying it to create android log messages, or even just to print messages to stdout and temporarily run it from the adb shell rather than the app.

Comment: It would be useful to know how the apps are communicating.  There is nothing about Android that would cause this, so you need to look at what the native app is doing.  Another quick thing you can do on recent devices is (as root) run `adb shell debuggerd -b <pid>`, where <pid> is the process ID of the native command, to get a dump of the native stacks and see where it has stalled.

Comment: If I run it from the adb shell, it works great. The same native process runs freely as soon as the Java app closes.  Also, I am logging lots of messages, and that's how i'm getting to getting to know that the process is stalled.

Comment: Ok, got the issue.  The native process had a lot of printf statements. And the 'stdout' of the native process was redirected to the parent process. [Is this the default behaviour]. The parent process was never reading this buffer. So, in the native process, the 'printf' line used to block.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, got the issue. 
The native process had a lot of printf statements. 
And the 'stdout' of the native process was redirected to the parent process. 
[Is this the default behaviour].

The parent process was never reading this buffer. So, in the native process, the 'printf' line used to block.

So when the parent process died, the redirection must have stopped, or set to /dev/null.
Hence the native process ran freely.

Is there anyway I can disable redirection of output in the Java code, while creating the process?